# Removing variables with group by or aggregate functions

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, aggregate, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers from a subset of observations grouped by a categorical variable. So that I can plot the boxplot without outliers and also get the t-stat of the new dataset.

I tried both 'group by' with data.table and aggregate with lists. However, always outliers are removed considering the whole dataset. Not from each subset.

Here is a part of the dataset. There are 40 column variables and 62 observations

```
> dput(head(dat, 30))
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SHAM+vehicle", "TAC+vehicle", 
"TAC+relaxin", "TAC+Enalapril"), class = "factor"), Comparison = c("TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", 
"TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", 
"TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", 
"TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(4hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", 
"TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", "TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", "TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", 
"TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", "TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", "TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", 
"TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", "TAC(4hrs)+relaxin", "SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", 
"SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", "SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", "SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", 
"SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", "SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", "SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", 
"SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", "SHAM(10hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(10hrs)+vehicle", 
"TAC(10hrs)+vehicle", "TAC(10hrs)+vehicle"), Mode = c("Prevention", 
"Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", 
"Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", 
"Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", "Prevention", 
"Prevention", "Prevention", "Intervention", "Intervention", "Intervention", 
"Intervention", "Intervention", "Intervention", "Intervention", 
"Intervention", "Intervention", "Intervention", "Intervention", 
"Intervention"), `Adiponectin/Acrp30` = c(1300000, 650000, 650000, 
650000, 1300000, 1300000, 1300000, 1300000, 1300000, 650000, 
650000, 650000, 650000, 650000, 1300000, 1300000, 1300000, 1300000, 
650000, 650000, 650000, 650000, 1300000, 650000, 650000, 1300000, 
1300000, 650000, 1300000, 650000), CRP = c(10666575, 3785850, 
3876595, 6287075, 5612955, 4544670, 9467470, 5632695, 8817655, 
4273610, 3560300, 10077690, 6504345, 4233480, 5425300, 2193250, 
6704455, 7838805, 5144890, 3636160, 4183640, 8913940, 3345130, 
4063455, 3823415, 8426135, 5877360, 5499595, 6996230, 2830510
), `Cystatin C` = c(565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 
565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 
565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 
565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000, 565000
), `Endoglin/CD105` = c(5460.36, 2405.94, 2613.33, 1249.04, 3545.37, 
2152.72, 1769.2, 695.94, 956.65, 1958.48, 3842.39, 3963.14, 1288.27, 
1046.94, 1097.09, 2377.61, 1858.56, 513.67, 1200.51, 2246.9, 
2907.68, 1632.56, 892.39, 988.96, 746.25, 682.59, 327.2, 1601.98, 
361.54, 692.6), Endostatin = c(29667.6, 22750.32, 21733.44, 23829.04, 
20203.12, 14614.88, 17822.56, 23132.24, 20265.84, 17495.76, 27424.16, 
17635.44, 22257.68, 34155.44, 16857.52, 18949.6, 25434.64, 22701.36, 
18186.16, 24013.12, 14673.92, 14092.4, 26438.4, 18384.4, 19220.96, 
18781.52, 19844.08, 23242.96, 23037.2, 22040.24), `FABP4/A-FABP` = c(2389.37, 
1143.58, 862.57, 376.15, 1368.68, 649.46, 370.47, 243.43, 378.48, 
605.82, 1458.3, 588.77, 616.45, 390.36, 403.54, 603.54, 804.06, 
244.41, 1025.16, 602.67, 948.18, 292.27, 260.56, 259.61, 243.58, 
240.89, 314.22, 395.73, 304.18, 836.27), `Fas (APO-1)` = c(24.57, 
10.13, 11.63, 1.25, 14.74, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 14.63, 
6.95, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 2.5, 1.25, 15.27, 5.68, 8.22, 1.25, 
1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 4.42), `FGF-21` = c(136.07, 
233.66, 63.28, 99.6, 190.43, 54.54, 141.27, 104.86, 136.07, 131.03, 
155.04, 75.54, 130.17, 191.02, 264.49, 97.75, 216.12, 204.42, 
431.37, 62.15, 90.38, 47.5, 74.84, 144.45, 88.4, 181.26, 232.14, 
128.01, 129.74, 771.73), `FGF-23` = c(244.06, 108.41, 140.06, 
168.71, 113.96, 129.91, 274.24, 135.03, 277.9, 168.71, 216.2, 
220.28, 207.95, 216.2, 129.91, 164.1, 111.2, 228.33, 276.07, 
159.42, 199.54, 145.01, 263.1, 238.22, 195.27, 124.7, 207.95, 
145.01, 51.94, 212.09)........
```

The code is as follows

```
dat_o = dat
setDT(dat_o)

for (j in col_names){
  
  dat_o[, (j) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(!x %in% boxplot.stats(dat_o[[j]])$out, x, NA)), 
              by = Comparison, .SDcols = j]
  
}

#aggregate function
aggregate(dat_o[[j]], by=list(dat_o$Comparison), 
            FUN= function(x) ifelse(!x %in% boxplot.stats(dat_o[[j]])$out, x, NA))
```

Where is the issue? Appreciate your insights and novel ideas to tackle this.

Comment: GedaraHome, do any of the answers address your issue? If there are still problems, perhaps [edit] your question with additional details to explain what else is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @r2evans . I am testing out the possibilities while trying the understand the coding. Sorry it is taking some time to test them. But I will respond soon

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dat)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dat, 20))`. Note that it's `dat`, not `dat_o`, please.

Comment: I have added the dataset. Thank you for your cooperation and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `dat_o[[..]]` within the `function(x)` is always using the whole frame, not just the subset/group you are intending to do. Also, there is no need to use a `for` loop, we can use `.SDcols`. I'll demonstrate with `mtcars`:

```r
library(data.table)
MT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
cols <- c("hp", "wt", "qsec")
MT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(z) fifelse(z %in% boxplot.stats(z)$out, z[NA], z)),
    .SDcols = cols][]
#       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#     <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
#  2:  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
#  3:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
#  4:  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
#  5:  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
#  6:  18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
#  7:  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4
#  8:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2
#  9:  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150    NA     1     0     4     2
# 10:  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.30     1     0     4     4
# 11:  17.8     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.90     1     0     4     4
# 12:  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3
# 13:  17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3
# 14:  15.2     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.780 18.00     0     0     3     3
# 15:  10.4     8 472.0   205  2.93 5.250 17.98     0     0     3     4
# 16:  10.4     8 460.0   215  3.00    NA 17.82     0     0     3     4
# 17:  14.7     8 440.0   230  3.23    NA 17.42     0     0     3     4
# 18:  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1
# 19:  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
# 20:  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1
# 21:  21.5     4 120.1    97  3.70 2.465 20.01     1     0     3     1
# 22:  15.5     8 318.0   150  2.76 3.520 16.87     0     0     3     2
# 23:  15.2     8 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2
# 24:  13.3     8 350.0   245  3.73 3.840 15.41     0     0     3     4
# 25:  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2
# 26:  27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1
# 27:  26.0     4 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2
# 28:  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2
# 29:  15.8     8 351.0   264  4.22 3.170 14.50     0     1     5     4
# 30:  19.7     6 145.0   175  3.62 2.770 15.50     0     1     5     6
# 31:  15.0     8 301.0    NA  3.54 3.570 14.60     0     1     5     8
# 32:  21.4     4 121.0   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2
#       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
```

FYI: I used `z[NA]` instead of just `NA` because `fifelse` enforces that both the `yes=` and `no=` arguments must be strictly of the same `class`; an isolated `NA` is technically of class `logical` (there are at least six types of `NA`, fyi), but `z[NA]` will always return the appropriate class of `NA` needed to satisfy `fifelse`. (`dplyr::if_else` is the same way. I consider `base::ifelse` a *little* sloppy ... perhaps more forgiving ... for not enforcing this, though it can lead to surprises if you are not expecting or prepared for it.)

(This methodology can be applied to base or `dplyr` methods as well.)

Comment: Hi @r2evans, you are the man! This code worked like a magic. I had to add the group by clause as it was committed in yours. Once it was added it worked perfectly. It took a while to understand how it works, in fact still not understanding fully. However, thanks!

Comment: You should also add an important note here that the operator `: =` is no longer used in R. It only remained in the `data.table` package!

Comment: @MarekFiołka, that is not *wholly* true, and there is no strict need to add a note: (1) OP is tagged with [tag:data.table], and I include `library(data.table)` in the answer; (2) `dplyr` uses the `:=` in meta-programming, as shown in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html. While base R is not using it, it is used in more than just `data.table`.

Comment: You originally received +15 rep and then when the OP changed their mind it was taken away (which may appear like you lose the points); since you received an upvote, you are +10 for the answer as a whole. I can only guess why the OP chose to change the accepted answer, but it is their prerogative.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. It surprised me a bit. Well, the PO decides. I'm new to stack overflow, and I'm not clear about everything yet.

Comment: I understand, each forum works on a different set of rules and expectations. Roll with it. Downvotes happen too, frustrating and perfectly anonymous; when that happens with no accompanying comment and I can see no obvious issue to suggest it, I get a little frustrated ... but alas, they are anonymous for really good reasons, so I just let it roll. Enjoy SO!

Answer (score 1):

### Base R

Here is a way with `ave`. Note that `ave` returns a vector of the same class as the vector being grouped, in this case a numeric vector, so in the subsetting it is coerced to logical.

```
i <- with(dat, ave(j, Comparison, FUN = function(x){
  !x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out
}))
dat[as.logical(i), ]
```

---

### Package `data.table`

The trick is, like above, to create a logical index on `j`,  grouped by `Comparison` and then subset on that index. But the index is created in a different way.

```
library(data.table)

dat_o <- dat
setDT(dat_o)

# This returns a logical index
dat_o[, sapply(.SD, function(x) !x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out), 
      by = Comparison, .SDcols = 'j'][[2]]
```

Now subset using the index.

```
dat_o[dat_o[, sapply(.SD, function(x) !x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out), 
      by = Comparison, .SDcols = 'j'][[2]], ]

nrow(dat_o)
#[1] 200
```

But it didn't change the data.table, it only selected the `TRUE` rows. The result must be assigned back to `dat_o`.

```
dat_o <- dat_o[dat_o[, sapply(.SD, function(x) !x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out), 
                     by = Comparison, .SDcols = 'j'][[2]], ]
nrow(dat_o)
#[1] 192
```

---

### Test data creation code.

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n, mean = 20)
x[sample(n, 3)] <- 11:13
y[sample(n, 3)] <- 101:103
boxplot.stats(x)$out
#[1] 13 12 11
boxplot.stats(y)$out
#[1]  17.29928  17.31704 102.00000 101.00000 103.00000

Comparison <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = n)
j <- c(x, y)
dat <- data.frame(Comparison, j)
```

Comment: Hi Rui Barradas, Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and it works nicely for the data set you have generated here. However, when I try to use my dataset with multiple column variables, it replaced the whole dataset with 'NA' values.  The adopted code that I used as follows `for (j in col_names){ dat_o <- dat_o[dat_o[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(!x %in% boxplot.stats(dat_o[[j]])$out, x, NA)), by = Comparison, .SDcols = j][[2]],] }` I am sorry for being naïve on troubleshooting

Comment: Btw. I used the ifelse function instead of what so have suggested as I don't want to delete the whole row when it becomes an outlier for one column variable

Comment: @GedaraHome See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69137822/removing-variables-with-group-by-or-aggregate-functions/69138042?noredirect=1#comment122233572_69137822) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I will also add my solution.
First, let's produce data with outliers.

```
library(tidyverse)

nrow=100
ncol=10

df = tibble(group = rep(1:ncol, each=nrow) %>% factor(),
            x = sample(c(-20:20, rnorm(nrow*ncol)), nrow*ncol)) 

df %>% ggplot(aes(group, x, fill=group))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]
Now let's do one little clever `f2` function that turns our outlier data into `NA` values

```
f2 = function(data) ifelse(data$x %in% boxplot.stats(data$x)$out, NA, data$x)
```

It's time to use our clever `f2` function

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, f2)) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, data, fill=group))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

It seems very elegant and simple.
Or maybe you would like to calculate statistics on such prepared data (without outliers)? Nothing simpler. See below.

```
fstat = function(x) tibble(
  mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
  sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
  median = median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
)

df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, f2),
         stat = map(data, fstat)) %>% 
  unnest(stat)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   group [10]
   group data            mean    sd   median
   <fct> <list>         <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 1     <dbl [100]>  0.0140  0.886  0.0513 
 2 2     <dbl [100]>  0.0398  1.11  -0.00458
 3 3     <dbl [100]> -0.00975 1.22   0.00258
 4 4     <dbl [100]>  0.0179  1.01  -0.0242 
 5 5     <dbl [100]>  0.0859  0.928  0.160  
 6 6     <dbl [100]> -0.0374  1.01  -0.00938
 7 7     <dbl [100]> -0.0451  0.945 -0.0277 
 8 8     <dbl [100]>  0.0330  1.06  -0.0535 
 9 9     <dbl [100]>  0.103   0.964  0.0577 
10 10    <dbl [100]>  0.112   1.08   0.0610
```

Comment: This code worked as explained. And easier to understand. Thanks @Marek Fiolka